# Installing NPM devDependencies via platform hooks on EB

Tags: node.js, npm, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, hook

I am running into a peculiar situation... Here's the rough idea of the setup:

It's a JavaScript Web App and my package.json looks roughly like this:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.17.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack && node index.js",
    "dev": "webpack --config webpack.develop.config.js && node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.18.2",
    
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "6.6.0",
    "style-loader": "1.0.1",
    "url-loader": "3.0.0",
    "webpack": "4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "4.7.0"
  }
}
```

When trying to deploy this on ElasticBeanstalk with `NODE_ENV` set to `production`, the devDependencies are not installed (makes sense). However, it causes the npm start script to fail with the following error:

```
Dec 20 20:03:52 ip-172-21-128-143 web: One CLI for webpack must be installed. These are recommended choices, delivered as separate packages:
Dec 20 20:03:52 ip-172-21-128-143 web: - webpack-cli (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli)
Dec 20 20:03:52 ip-172-21-128-143 web: The original webpack full-featured CLI.
Dec 20 20:03:52 ip-172-21-128-143 web: We will use "npm" to install the CLI via "npm install -D".
Dec 20 20:03:56 ip-172-21-128-143 web: Do you want to install 'webpack-cli' (yes/no):
```

So I figured that perhaps I can use a predeploy platform hook to install it. Something simple like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Installing webpack-cli"
npm install webpack-cli@4.7.0 webpack@4.41.2
```

And although I do see the hook running and seemingly installing the webpack-cli & webpack, the application fails to start with the same error message.

I am a little bit lost as to what I am missing here. Is this an order of operations issue, or a permissions thing? From what I see in the eb-engine.log it does `npm install` first, THEN runs the predeploy hook, so I assumed it would have webpack installed before trying to run `npm start` ...

Quick Edit 1:

I have also tried the command inside the hook with `--save` and `-D` and `-g` arguments.